# Join on several conditions without duplicated columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Joining on identity with Spark leads to the common key column being duplicated in the final Dataset:

```
val result = ds1.join(ds2, ds1("key") === ds2("key"))
// result now has two "key" columns
```

This is avoidable by using a `Seq` instead of the comparison, similar to `USING` keyword in SQL:

```
val result = ds1.join(ds2, Seq("key"))
// result now has only one "key" column
```

However, this doesn't work when joining with a common key + another condition, like:

```
val result = ds1.join(ds2, ds1("key") === ds2("key") && ds1("foo") < ds2("foo"))
// result has two "key" columns

val result = ds1.join(ds2, Seq("key") && ds1("foo") < ds2("foo"))
// compile error: value && is not a member of Seq[String]
```

Currently one way of getting out of this is to drop the duplicated column afterwards, but this is quite cumbersome:

```
val result = ds1.join(ds2, ds1("key") === ds2("key") && ds1("foo") < ds2("foo"))
                .drop(ds1("key"))
```

Is there a more natural, cleaner way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can separate equi join component and filter:

```
ds1.join(ds2, Seq("key")).where(ds1("foo") < ds2("foo"))
```